# Drag and Drop not working in Cocoa

Tags: macos, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nscollectionview

I've implemented the `acceptDrop` and the `validateDrop` functions, and also the `registerForTypes`, but when I drag an item it does not even show the plus sign.

```
extension Document: NSCollectionViewDelegate {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, validateDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, proposedIndex proposedDropIndex: UnsafeMutablePointer<Int>, dropOperation proposedDropOperation: UnsafeMutablePointer<NSCollectionViewDropOperation>) -> NSDragOperation {
        return NSDragOperation.copy
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: NSCollectionView, acceptDrop draggingInfo: NSDraggingInfo, index: Int, dropOperation: NSCollectionViewDropOperation) -> Bool {
        let pasteboard = draggingInfo.draggingPasteboard()
        if pasteboard.types?.contains(NSURLPboardType) == true, let url = NSURL(from: pasteboard) as? URL {
            do {
                try self.addAttachmentAtURL(url)
                attachmentsList.reloadData()
                return true
            } catch let error as NSError {
                self.presentError(error)
                return false
            }
        }
        return false
    }
}

override func windowControllerDidLoadNib(_ windowController: NSWindowController) {
    self.attachmentsList.register(forDraggedTypes: [NSURLPboardType])
}
```

Comment: Pleas include the code so it's easier to find the problem

Comment: Do you drag a `NSURLPboardType`? Did you connect/set the delegate?

Comment: @Willeke, I drag a regular file. A delegate for what?

Comment: Did you connect or set the delegate of the collection view to the document?

Comment: @Willeke, yes, I did.

Comment: Is `self.attachmentsList` pointing to the collection view in `windowControllerDidLoadNib`? Is `validateDrop` called?

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand.

Comment: Did you check if `validateDrop` is executed? Did you check if `windowControllerDidLoadNib` is executed?

Comment: How can I do that? `viewControllerDidLoadNib` is executed because other lines of code here work

Comment: Add a breakpoint in `validateDrop` and `windowControllerDidLoadNib`.